# Need to make tooltip border color same as marker color using Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to make this graphic:

[image]

But I need to make the border color of the tooltip to be the same as the marker color, so when I hover on the green marker the border color turns green, in the yellow marker the border color turns yellow and the same with the red marker. Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

**Updated:** Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbU7e/1/

Comment: You need to change the CSS class related to it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `borderColor` to `null` and then pass the point `color` with your `point` data, like the following.

```
var current_zafra_series = new Array();
current_zafra_series[0] = { y: 150, prueba: 'a', color: '#FF9933',marker: { fillColor: '#FF9933' } };
current_zafra_series[1] = { y: 200, prueba: 'b', color: '#F15B49', marker: { fillColor: '#F15B49' } };
current_zafra_series[2] = { y: 150, prueba: 'c', color: '#55B647', marker: { fillColor: '#55B647' } };
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbU7e/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much! We where looking for help everywhere and we didn't found anything. I worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.borderColor) you could just set the option to null. so when declaring your chart make sure to add the following option

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      //... other options ,
      tooltip : {
           borderColor : null
       }

 });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbU7e/1/

When hovering on the markers, I need to change the border color of the tooltip to be the same as the marker